# Mysql search with 2 times AND on the same field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I have a search query for searching factories in a radius of x km around the input (postal code). It is working fine, but the problem is I can't search for the input (postal code) so when i type in 9101 for example it does not search for that postal code, only for the ones around it.

My query looks like this:

```
$string = implode($_SESSION['postcodes'], '|');

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM (`bedrijfcategorieen`) 
        JOIN `bedrijven` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven` = `bedrijven`.`idbedrijven` 
        JOIN `categorieen` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idcategorieen` = `categorieen`.`idcategorieen` 
        WHERE (`Bedrijfsnaam` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Plaats` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Telefoonnummer` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Email` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Website` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Profiel` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Adres` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Categorie` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%') 
        AND (Postcode REGEXP '$string')

        GROUP BY `Categorie`,  `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven`";
        $query = $this->db->query($query);
        echo '<pre>';
        echo '</pre>';
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
```

The `$_SESSION['postcodes']` is the session with all the postcodes in a certain radius around my postcode.
I have another session called `searched_post_code` this one is for the input so '9101' for example.

How can I search for factories with the filled in postal code and my filled in search term?

My searchform looks like this:

[image: searchbox]

Note the large 'Search' input and the radius and postal code inputs.

I also want to match any of the searchterms with the postal code I search on.

Code for the form:

```
<form name="input" method="post" action="searchresults" class="pro6pp_range">
<input type="search" onchange="validate()" placeholder="Zoeken..." name="search" size="70">
      <select class="range">
        <option value="5" selected="selected">5 km</option>
        <option value="10">10 km</option>
        <option value="15">15 km</option>
        <option value="20">20 km</option>
        <option value="25">25 km</option>
      </select>
    <input type="search" name="searchpc" class="postcode" value="<?= $this->input->cookie('postcode'); ?>" placeholder="Postcode (1234)" maxlength="4">
    <input type="submit" value="Zoeken">
```

I hope it's a bit clear:

You can see it working [HERE](http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/home/search)

Example of sql output:

> SELECT * FROM (`bedrijfcategorieen`) JOIN `bedrijven` ON
>   `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven` = `bedrijven`.`idbedrijven` JOIN
>   `categorieen` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idcategorieen` =
>   `categorieen`.`idcategorieen` WHERE (`Bedrijfsnaam` LIKE '%design%' OR
>   `Plaats` LIKE '%design%' OR `Telefoonnummer` LIKE '%design%' OR
>   `Email` LIKE '%design%' OR `Website` LIKE '%design%' OR `Profiel` LIKE
>   '%design%' OR `Adres` LIKE '%design%' OR `Categorie` LIKE '%design%')
>   AND (Postcode REGEXP
>   '9100|9101|9121|9103|9148|9156|9146|9122|9155|9154|9147|9125|9144|9106|9138|9113|9104|9153|')
>   GROUP BY `Categorie`, `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven`

Comment: How does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: see my edit. I use it straight in codeigniter so can't really give you a better example.

Comment: I cannot see any aggregating functions in your query, so what's the `GROUP BY` for? Also, table aliases anyone?

Comment: the group by is for my results. when i don't use that it gives me the same factory more than 1 time in my searchresults.

Comment: I also tried doing AND (Postcode REGEXP '$string') AND (Postcode REGEXP '$string2') where string2 is my session['searched_post_code'] but that did not work.

Comment: Will using WHERE IN on postal codes make sense in your case?

Comment: I tried that. but it did not work. maybe I did it wrong

Comment: It seems like IN should work...   AND (Postcode IN(REPLACE('$string','|',',')) - but the GROUP BY is still strange.

Comment: GROUP BY is nessesary because when i leave it out of the code it gives me more than 1 of the same factory. so when I search on design and it gives me companydesign for example. it will show 3 times companydesign. but when i use group by, it only shows that company once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I get what your problem is now.. What you want is to add the postcode you searched for to the `$string`

```
$postcodes = (is_array($_SESSION['postcodes']) ? $_SESSION['postcodes'] : array());
$postcodes[] =  $_SESSION['searched_post_code'];
$postcodes = array_filter(filter_var_array($postcodes, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
$string = join('|', $postcodes);
```

I added some simple integer validation on the values in the array, you should definitely have a look at either sanitise your data or use PDO and prepared statements.

As suggested in the comments, using `IN` will probably be better

```
 $string = join(',', $postcodes);
.. AND (Postcode IN ($string)) ..
```